# What are the Valid values of the searchboxex AppQueryTerms enum?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, web-parts

I'm building a custom search page and attempting to use an existing custom search scope.  I'm having success using the SearchBoxEx with the AppQueryTerms = "ContentType:'my custom content type name'" but when i try using AppQueryTerms = "Scope:'My Custom Search Scope'" I get no errors, but also no proper results.  I know my scope is populated using the advanced search so I must be using AppQuwryTerms wrong.

I've searched the net over and can't find the list of allowed AppQueryTerms filters.  Is this Enum know to the stackerverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your scope name has spaces.

This worked for me:

```
AppQueryTerms="Scope:&quot;My Scope&quot;"
```

Answer (score 1):

The values for `SearchBoxEx.AppQueryTerms` are not an enum.  They're actually a query written in a specific language for SharePoint Searching.  The syntax for SharePoint 2010 is defined by microsoft on this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx).  It follows the format `<Property Name><Property Operator><Property Value>`

- `Scope` is your property name.
- `:` is your property operator for
  matching using the property store database.
- `My Scope` is your
  property value.

The page above states:

> The property restriction must not include white space between the property name, property operator, and the property value, or the property restriction will be treated as a free-text query. The length of a property restriction is limited to 2,048 characters.

Therefore, as in HelloSharePoint's example, you have to wrap the property value in quotes if it includes spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Does your custom scope appear in the web sites list of Scopes?
http://intranet/[sitecollection]/_layouts/viewscopes.aspx?mode=site

Does the scope appear in a Display Group?